# Avoid line break getting inserted when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is what I have in the UI-

```
View by Team <dropdown list> (OR) Click on image to navigate
```

When a particular team is selected from the dropdown, UI gets displayed like this -

```
View by Team <dropdown list>
Home
```

When I click on Home, I want the UI to be  -

```
View by Team <dropdown list> (OR) Click on image to navigate
```

But I'm getting the UI as -

```
View by Team <dropdown list> 
(OR) Click on image to navigate
```

In the source code, I have -

```
<div id="teamList"><select><options></select>
    <span id="text">(OR) Click on image to navigate</span>
</div>
```

In the javascript function for selection of team from dropdown, I have specified -

```
document.getElementById('text').style.display='none';
```

How do I prevent the additional line break from appearing?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving home in another span like this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
          document.getElementById('text').style.display='none';
        });
      </script>
     </head>
    <body> 
      <div id="teamList"><select><options></select>
        <span id="text">(OR) Click on image to navigate</span>
        <span>Home</span>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BnFpJ/

Comment: Home is in another div. I'm referring only to span class "text" within div class "teamList"

Comment: oki i have updated the fiddle do check it. Try to include both the division in another common outer division and make the inner divisions to float left, and give margin to the home division so that it wont stick to dropdown.Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BnFpJ/1/

Answer (score 0):

try to add this simple css to your div

```
#teamList{
white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: have you checked the width of your div if it is big enough for the dropdown and image?